# how to pass value of td(which has been created by while loop) and pass it to the textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

While loop creates rows, but below function only pick value of first row td and put in textbox, i want it pick the value of td which has been clicked. not first one. Please help

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
<tr>
<td id='tbltd' onclick='getstock_id();'>",$row["stock_id"],"</td></tr>
}

<script>
    function getstock_id() {        
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML;
    var result = document.getElementById('stk');    
    result.value = myBox1;
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should not have multiple `id` with same value in a document. In your case, first element is being selected in `document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML`

Try this:

```
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 ?>
 <tr>
<td id='tbltd' onclick='getstock_id("<?php echo $row["stock_id"]; ?>");'><?php echo $row["stock_id"]; ?></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>

<script>
 function getstock_id(val) {
  var result = document.getElementById('stk');
  result.value = val;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to passed in your function param the node reference like that:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
<tr>
<td id='tbltd' onclick='getstock_id(this);'>",$row["stock_id"],"</td></tr>
}

<script>
    function getstock_id(refNode) {           
    document.getElementById('stk').value = refNode.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```